# How to fix gulp windows script host error in vscode

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, gulp, vscode-tasks

Gulp watch task runner error. It results in a  windows script host error.

I've already tried to change the file task.json:

```
{
    // See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkId=733558
    // for the documentation about the tasks.json format
    "version": "2.0.0",
    "command": "gulp",
    "isShellCommand": true,
    "args": [
        "--no-color"
    ],
    "tasks": [
        {
            "taskName": "scripts",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "always"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "sass",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "always"
        },
        {
            "taskName": "watch",
            "isBuildCommand": true,
            "showOutput": "always"
        }
    ]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you are using older syntax.  I don't believe `taskname` is supported anymore for example.

Here is a tasks.json file that I use and both methods of calling gulp commands work.  (You mentioned `task.json`, I assume that is a typo, it is `tasks.json`)

```
{
"version": "2.0.0",
"tasks": [
    {
        "label": "Start server and process files",
        "command": "gulp",
        "args": [
            "sync"
        ],
        "type": "shell",
        "options": {
            "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}"
        }
    },
    {
        "label": "Gulp: Start server only",

        "type": "gulp",
        "task": "serve",
        "problemMatcher": []
    },
    {
        "label": "Gulp: watch",

        "type": "gulp",
        "task": "watch",
        "problemMatcher": []
    }
}
```

It looks like you also want:

```
"group": "build",
```

in each of your tasks - that replaces the `isBuildCommand` syntax you used above.

And:

```
"presentation": {
  "reveal": "always",
},
```

instead of the `showoutput` syntax.

See [migrating to tasks 2.0 documentation](https://code.visualstudio.com/Docs/editor/tasks#_migrating-to-tasks-200).